# Implementing Passcode screen in android

Tags: android, xml

I need to build a Passcode screen which should get 4 numeric characters and I have 4 input image view inside the grid layout above the keypad while i am giving input the circle should fill color to indicate that the input is taken.
Like this it should fill the color:

Passcode_Screen.Java

```
    public class Passcode_Screen extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    String userEntered;
    String userPin = "1234";
    final int PIN_LENGTH = 4;
    boolean keyPadLockedFlag = false;
    Context appContext;
    TextView titleView;
    TextView pinBox0;
    TextView pinBox1;
    TextView pinBox2;
    TextView pinBox3;
    TextView pinBox4;


    TextView statusView;

    Button button0;
    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    Button button3;
    Button button4;
    Button button5;
    Button button6;
    Button button7;
    Button button8;
    Button button9;
    Button button10;
    Button buttonExit;
    Button buttonDelete;
    EditText passwordInput;
    ImageView backSpace;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        appContext = this;
        userEntered = "";


        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        // set the view content
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_passcode__screen);

        //Typeface xpressive=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/XpressiveBold.ttf");

        statusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusview);
        passwordInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Result);
        backSpace = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        buttonExit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonexit);
        backSpace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                passwordInput.setText(passwordInput.getText().toString().substring(0, passwordInput.getText().toString().length() - 2));
            }
        });
        buttonExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                          public void onClick(View v) {

//                                              //Exit app
//                                              Intent i = new Intent();
//                                              i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
//                                              i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
//                                              appContext.startActivity(i);
//                                              finish();

                                              Intent camera = new Intent(Passcode_Screen.this, MainActivity.class);
                                              startActivity(camera);

                                          }

                                      }
        );
        //buttonExit.setTypeface(xpressive);


        buttonDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttondelete);
        buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                                if (keyPadLockedFlag == true) {
                                                    return;
                                                }

                                                if (userEntered.length() > 0) {
                                                    userEntered = userEntered.substring(0, userEntered.length() - 1);
                                                    passwordInput.setText("");
                                                }


                                            }
                                        }
        );





        titleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
        //titleView.setTypeface(xpressive);


        View.OnClickListener pinButtonHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (keyPadLockedFlag == true) {
                    return;
                }

                Button pressedButton = (Button) v;


                if (userEntered.length() < PIN_LENGTH) {
                    userEntered = userEntered + pressedButton.getText();
                    Log.v("PinView", "User entered=" + userEntered);

                    //Update pin boxes
                    passwordInput.setText(passwordInput.getText().toString() + "*");
                    passwordInput.setSelection(passwordInput.getText().toString().length());

                    if (userEntered.length() == PIN_LENGTH) {
                        //Check if entered PIN is correct
                        if (userEntered.equals(userPin))
                        {
                            Intent login = new Intent(Passcode_Screen.this,Site_screen.class);
                            startActivity(login);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PIN Invalid",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    //Roll over
                    passwordInput.setText("");

                    userEntered = "";

                   // statusView.setText("");

                    userEntered = userEntered + pressedButton.getText();
                    Log.v("PinView", "User entered=" + userEntered);

                    //Update pin boxes
                    passwordInput.setText("8");

                }


            }
        };


        button0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
        //button0.setTypeface(xpressive);
        button0.setOnClickListener(pinButtonHandler);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        //button1.setTypeface(xpressive);
        button1.setOnClickListener(pinButtonHandler);

        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        //button2.setTypeface(xpressive);
        button2.setOnClickListener(pinButtonHandler);


        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        //button3.setTypeface(xpressive);
        button3.setOnClickListener(pinButtonHandler);

        button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        //button4.setTypeface(xpressive);
        button4.setOnClickListener(pinButtonHandler);

        button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        //button5.setTypeface(xpressive);
        button5.setOnClickListener(pinButtonHandler);

        button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        //button6.setTypeface(xpressive);
        button6.setOnClickListener(pinButtonHandler);

        button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        //button7.setTypeface(xpressive);
        button7.setOnClickListener(pinButtonHandler);

        button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        //button8.setTypeface(xpressive);
        button8.setOnClickListener(pinButtonHandler);

        button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
        //button9.setTypeface(xpressive);
        button9.setOnClickListener(pinButtonHandler);


        buttonDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttondelete);
        //buttonDelete.setTypeface(xpressive);


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //App not allowed to go back to Parent activity until correct pin entered.
        return;
        //super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_pin_entry_view, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }


    private class LockKeyPadOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return "Executed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            statusView.setText("");

            //Roll over
            passwordInput.setText("");
            ;

            userEntered = "";

            keyPadLockedFlag = false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }


    }
    }
```

activity_passcode_screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
  >

    <View
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_above="@+id/numericPad"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/view" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/view"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="1"
        android:rowCount="4"
        android:id="@+id/glResult"
        android:layout_below="@+id/statusview"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/imvPin1"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/imvPin2"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/imvPin3"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/imvPin4"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@id/numericPad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/glResult"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <Button android:text="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            android:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="16dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            />

        <Button android:text="2"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            android:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="16dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

        <Button android:text="3"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            android:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="16dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            />



        <Button android:text="4"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            android:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="16dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

        <Button android:text="5"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            android:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="16dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="48dp" android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />


        <Button android:text="6"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            android:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="16dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            />

        <Button android:text="7"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            android:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="16dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

        <Button android:text="8"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            android:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="16dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

        <Button android:text="9"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            android:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="16dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="48dp"/>

        <Button

            android:text="0"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:id="@+id/button0"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            android:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="16dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="48dp"

            />


    </GridLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Enter Password"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/statusview"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back"
        android:id="@+id/buttonexit"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttondelete" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Reset"
        android:id="@+id/buttondelete"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here instead of Edit text (passcodeInput) where i am storing the input value i have removed that and i need to add image view field and to fill the circles with color when a button is pressed, should fill from circle 1 to 4 linearly and when the 4th input is filling it should validate the entire input to the default given input if it matches it should move to the next activity else should show error message.

I need like this image :

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smart.mobile.lin.pin.locker

I don't have much knowledge in Android so please help me to figure out this. Please share any tutorial links or sample code for the above question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A side comment: when variable names end with a number, you should use a list or array.

Comment: Ok Thanks.. Please tell how to change fill the image view (circle) when the button is pressed.

Comment: I suggest you google ImageView and familiarize yourself within the documentation. Very likely it will answer your question.